# align CSS triangle dynamically based on div width

Tags: css, geometry

i have created this http://jsfiddle.net/nuUcv/1/  div filling by following tutorial. i have a trianlge down to that , currently it is static.i want to place it dynamically based on inner div width(the one which i am filling).How can i achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.progress').animate({ width: '90%' }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: ***place it dynamically based on inner div width*** - this does not make much sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

first we have to get width of inner div that is following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var width1=$(".your_inner_div").width();
$('.progress').animate({ width: width1 }, 1000);
});
```